# How do I present multiple alert controllers in a for loop in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I am having issues with presenting multiple alert controllers one after another. Want I want to do is have my for loop wait until the user dismisses the response controller.
My code for presenting a message is below.

```swift
for block in blocks {
     self.presentMessage(title: codeBlock.stringInput1, message: codeBlock.stringInput2)
}
```

```swift
func presentMessage(title: String, message: String, completion: @escaping (Bool)->()) {
     let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

     alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: { action in
          completion(true)
     }))

     self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Edit --

This is my block class

```swift
class block: Codable {
    var type: String
    var stringInput1: String
    var stringInput2: String

    init(t: String, i1: String, i2: String) {
        type = t
        stringInput1 = i1
        stringInput2 = i2
    }
}
```

I have tried to use dispatch groups already but I was unsuccessful at getting it to correctly work. The end goal for my setup is to have the blocks be able to execute different actions depending on the type of the block. 
If it is possible I would like to make my for loops wait for the completion of a function until it continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift only lets you present one view controller at a time, so you'd have to do something like this:

```
var blocks: [Block] = [Block.init(one: "1", two: "12"),
                        Block.init(one: "2", two: "22"),
                        Block.init(one: "3", two: "32")]

func nextMessage(index: Int) {
    if index < blocks.count {
        let codeBlock = blocks[index]
        self.presentMessage(index: index, title: codeBlock.stringInput1, message: codeBlock.stringInput2)
    }
}
func presentMessage(index: Int, title: String, message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: { action in
        self.nextMessage(index: index + 1)
    }))

     self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Calling presentMessage from the first item in the array will start it:

```
self.presentMessage(index: 0, title: blocks[0].stringInput1, message: blocks[0].stringInput2)
```

> This is the quick and dirty Block class I created, but posting any
>   related code like this in the future would be helpful for those
>   answering questions.

```
class Block {
    var stringInput1: String
    var stringInput2: String

    init(one: String, two: String) {
        stringInput1 = one
        stringInput2 = two
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Currently this is my block setup  ```swift class block: Codable {
    var type: String
    var stringInput1: String
    var stringInput2: String
    
    init(t: String, i1: String, i2: String) {
        type = t
        stringInput1 = i1
        stringInput2 = i2
    }
}
``` It is setup right now for expansion into different types of blocks then just messages. Would it be possible to just have my for loop just wait until a function completes?

Comment: You could use custom DispatchGroups or Operations, but those are more meant for long-running background tasks. They are also a bit complex to implement and incorrect usage can result in your app hanging.

Comment: Also please accept this answer if it solves your question. Happy I could help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after some work I adapted @elliott-io 's answer into something that would work for me. Here is my final solution to my problem.

```swift
func nextBlock(index: Int) {
    if index < codeBlocks.count {
        let type = codeBlocks[index].type
        if type == "message" {
            self.presentMessage(title: codeBlocks[index].stringInput1, message: codeBlocks[index].stringInput2, index: index)
        } else if type == "link" {
            self.openLink(webpage: codeBlocks[index].stringInput1, index: index)
        }
    }
}

func presentMessage(title: String, message: String, index: Int) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: { action in
        self.nextBlock(index: index + 1)
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

The reason I am using this as my solution is that I want to be able to have multiple things that a block can do.